# Eliminar el último elemento de un vector de una lista en R

Tags: r, lista, rstudio

soy un poco nuevo en R studio y estoy buscando eliminar el último elemento de cada vector de la lista adjunta. Es decir, quisiese eliminar el ultimo "2,00", el "19,00", el "7,00", etc.

La lista tiene por nombre "cantidades" y mediante el siguiente código podría hacerlo:

```
cantidades$`1764149` <- cantidades$`1764149`[-2]
```

Sin embargo, los datos de la lista, el nombre de estas y su cantidad de elementos es dinámico, y por tanto no me sirve tanto llamar mediante `$`, ni tampoco poner manualmente la posición que quiero eliminar. Solamente quiero eliminar el último y solo el último.

Agradecería si ustedes saben una forma un poco mas genérica, espero haberme podido explicar bien. Gracias de antemano.

[image: Salida del código de la lista]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma bien simple y al estilo R es usar `lapply()` para iterar implicitamente sobre cada elemento del vector:

```
new_cantidades <- lapply(cantidades, FUN = function(x) head(x,-1))
```

Por cada elemento de la lista se aplica la función `head(x,-1)` que justamente eliminia el último valor de cada vector.

Answer (score 1):

Sólo haré el ejemplo para los cuatro primeros vectores de tu lista. Ya que resulta engorroso copiar todos los vectores.

Por tanto, si se tiene la lista siguiente:

```
cantidades<-list("176149"=c("2","2"), "1765259"=c("5","1","5","4","1","3","19"),
                 "1764150"=c("2","1","2","2","7"), "1764686"=c("9","9"))
```

El código para eliminar los últimos elementos lo haría con un `for`.

```
for (i in 1:length(cantidades)) {
  cantidades[[i]]<-cantidades[[i]][-length(cantidades[[i]])]
}
```

El doble corchete `[[]]` se usa para llamar a vectores de una lista y la función `length()` para calcular el tamaño de cada vector. Con lo cual se consigue eliminar los últimos elementos de cada vector.